# Erro ao executar o setOnClickListener

Tags: java, android

Não estou conseguindo fazer um cálculo simples de IMC. Esse é o erro que aparece na imagem.

[image: StackOverflow Log]

**Código:**

```
 ButtonCalcular.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        /* Variáveis que recebem o conteúdo do Edit*/
        String valorPeso   = EdtPeso.getText().toString();
        String valorAltura = EdtAltura.getText().toString();

        if (isCampoVazio(valorPeso) || (isCampoVazio(valorAltura))){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), R.string.MSG_Preencher_Campos, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{

           double imc =  CalculaImc(Double.parseDouble(valorPeso), Double.parseDouble(valorAltura));
           TextImc.setText(String.valueOf(imc));
        }
    }
});
```

**Método que realiza o cálculo do IMC:**

```
//FUNÇÃO QUE FAZ O CÁLCULO DO ÍNDICE DE MASSA CORPORAL
private double CalculaImc(double peso, double altura){

    double resultado = peso/(altura * altura);
    return resultado;
}
```

**Erro:**

> ```
> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                   Process: net.ddns.tiyuri.trimc, PID: 14839
>                   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{net.ddns.tiyuri.trimc/net.ddns.tiyuri.trimc.Calcular}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2830)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606)
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595)
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
>                       at net.ddns.tiyuri.trimc.Calcular.onCreate(Calcular.java:64)
>                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7016)
>                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1214)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2905) 
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1606) 
>                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:169) 
>                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6595) 
>                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767) 
> I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, data=28KB
> I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=28KB
> I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
> I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=23KB, data=48KB
> I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=23KB, data=48KB
> I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
> I/zygote64: Compiler allocated 8MB to compile void android.widget.TextView.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int)
> ```

Comment: Por favor envie o erro em forma de texto, fica mais fácil de analisar o que está acontecendo, está faltando algumas partes da exceção

Comment: tudo bem, irei fazer isso.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, colocando o código e o erro.
Desculpe por qualquer coisa, é a primeira vez que utilizo o stack Overflow.

Comment: O botão `ButtonCalcular` não existe na *activity*

Comment: Valdeir, era exatamente isso, vi aqui e realmente ao referenciar o nome do botão, coloquei o nome de um outro botão.
obrigado pela ajuda.